# How to identify an expand collapse icon with this class name:

Tags: python-3.x

i class=material-icons et-icon-xs toggleButtonIconOpen - If the element is open

i class=material-icons et-icon-xs toggleButtonIcon i /> - If element is closed

Comment: hay @Prasad can you write it your code clearly and give it a brief decription.

Comment: div class = "expand-collapse"
<button aria-expanded="true" aria-label="test" class="btn medium-header btn-link" type="button">
<i class="material-icons et-icon-xs toggle-button-icon-open" aria-hidden="true">keyboard_arrow_right</i>xyz
</button>The only dynamic text that changes is the class name which has to be figured via the xpath